# How do i remove default route in cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I can do it easily with other framework. I'm also search google but just see how to solve it in cakephp 2.

I can access same action with these urls
ad/contact/edit/10

contact/edit-genre/10

i want to delete the first one which is default.

My router file

```
 Router::prefix('ad', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/login', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
    $routes->connect('/contact/add-genre', ['controller' => 'Contact', 'action' => 'add']);
    $routes->connect('/contact/edit-genre/:id', ['controller' => 'Contact', 'action' => 'edit'],['id' => '\d+', 'pass' => ['id']]);
    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this line

```
$routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
```

After that you will need to connect the the rest of the routes yourself for that prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Now in CakePHP 3.1, default fallbacks is DashedRoute

Then remove this line:

```
$routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
```

Assuming you have fully customised all of your other routes.